# IIS Q: How can I configure IIS executable extensions & custerr?

Tags: permissions, asp-classic, web-config, iis-6, extension-methods

Please don't blame this question and I would be grateful if you can give me a specific answer.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 6.0 x86 with MsSQL 08.

**1. I want to limit the extension of IIS executable files on my web server.**

> ex:)
>
> Before set limit.
>
> Executable extension : *.asp | *.aspx ...
>
> After set limit.
>
> Executable extension : only *.asp

When I change values on column 'Path' with '*.cust', *.asp -> *.cust, *.cer -> *.cust, *.aspx -> *.cust on **Handler Mappings** like this, the browser always return 404 error.

Test file : '\wwwroot\main\test.asp' & '\wwwroot\main\test.cust'

When I call '/main/test.asp', browser returns 404.3 "Not found" error.

When I call '/main/test.cust', browser returns 404.0 "Not found" error.

Why this happens?

I don't know exactly what the **Handler Mappings** menu is.

**2. How to set 404 custerr when I call specified file?**

Test file on 'C:\inetpu\wwwroot\main\test.browser'.

When I call this file on browser, it returns 404.7

```
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.
```

Why this happens? is there any way to see the content of 'test.browser'?
or is it impossible?

Someone please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I cannot get error when I changed value of path as '*.cust'.

Comment: Set only *.asp to *.cust, you can see the result.

Comment: Thank you, but where can I find executable extensions? In **Handler Mappings**?

Comment: See the **Request Filtering** pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) You can customize executable extension on `Handler Mappings` pane.**

[image]

**2) You can customize specific error on `Request Filtering` pane & `Error Pages` pane.**

[image]

**If you call that URI on browser(Chrome) you will get `HTTP Error 404.5 - Not Found`.**